# Contact Picker Result

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, contactscontract

I'm using the ContactPicker for my app. I'm using this [this](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/1/) tutorial to build my onActivityResult method. I can't get the content revolver to build;

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

Doesn't work, the app crashes and I can't tell what kind ox exception it's throwing, if any. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);  
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {  
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {  
    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));   
    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));  
    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {  
    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                   cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
            null, 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
            new String[]{id}, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {  
            // Do something with phones  
            }   
            pCur.close();
        }  
            }  
            }  
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you are running the app in debug through eclipse and you should be able to see the exception in the logcat view.

Comment: Did you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> in your manifest?

Comment: @LadaRaider I did add the permission, but for some reason says logcat I didn't...                                             `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<!-- AdMob SDK requires Internet permission -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`   is what I have in my manifest.

Comment: Can you post your manifest file?

Comment: @LadaRaider I'm having trouble with the markup here--it's being wonky and won't display all the code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`
Doesn't work for a permission even though it's technically correct.
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"> </uses-permission>`
This works.